# Can a register hold multiple values at a time?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, simd, cpu-registers, swar

In the case of a 64-bit x86 register, is it possible to hold more than one value at a time in the same register, if the size of an value is small enough such that multiple instructions could fit into a register? For example fitting two 32 bit ints into one register. Would this be a bad thing to do if it is possible? I've been reading up on registers and I'm quite new to the concept.

Comment: Yes, it is quite common to pack multiple values into a single register. The mmx and xmm (incl. ymm and zmm) registers are specifically designed for this.

Comment: A 64 bit register holds 64 bits, 64 items, what those 64 bits mean is wholly owned by the programmer the processor has no idea.  So anywhere between one value and 64 can be held a 64 bit register.

Comment: it is slower to work with memory so holding two 32 bit values in a register has the potential to be faster, reading 64 bits from memory is faster than reading two 32 bit items (although the x86 overhead generally masks this).  At the same time it can take more instructions to maintain more than one item in a register in general, the x86 has the RAX/EAX/AX/AH/AL thing which can help but not completely solve it.  So it is a trade off.  For an x86 though there generally isnt a benefit for trying to do this.  other architectures, perhaps. depends specifically on the problem being solved.

Comment: A struct of many fields, as long as its total size is 64-bits or less, can fit entirely within a register.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registers don't hold instructions, but I'll assume you meant fitting multiple *values* into one register, so that you can add them both with one instruction.

---

**Yes, this is called [SIMD.  (Single Instruction, Multiple Data)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)**  On x86-64, SSE2 (Streaming SIMD Extensions) is guaranteed to be available, so you have sixteen different 16-byte registers (xmm0..15).  And you have instructions that can do packed FP add/sub/mul/div/sqrt/cmp of 4x 32-bit floats, 2x 64-bit double, packed integer add/sub/cmp/shift/etc for byte, word, dword, and qword operand-sizes.

(With some gaps; SSE2 is not very orthogonal, e.g. narrowest shift is 16-bit, packed min/max only available for certain sizes.  Some of these gaps are filled in by SSE4.1).

And bitwise-boolean stuff where element width is irrelevant (until AVX512 with mask registers...)

See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/.  `p...` instructions like `paddw` are packed-integer.  `...ps` and `pd` are floating point packed-single or packed-double.

Compilers frequently use SSE/SSE2 instructions like [`movdqa`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVDQA:VMOVDQA32:VMOVDQA64.html) to zero or copy memory in 16-byte chunks, as well as to "vectorize" (use SIMD computations) for loops over arrays.  And GCC 7 or 8 and later know how to coalesce loads/stores of adjacent struct members or array elements into a scalar load or store using RAX, for example.

e.g. this sum of an array:

```
int sumarr(const int *arr)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < 10240; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

compiles like this with GCC9.3 -O3 for x86-64 [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/gZTdbV)

```
sumarr:
        lea     rax, [rdi+40960]            # endp = arr + size
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
.L2:                                        # do {
        movdqu  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]        # v = arr[i + 0..3]
        add     rdi, 16                        # p += 4
        paddd   xmm0, xmm2                     # sum += v  // packed addition of 4 elements
        cmp     rax, rdi
        jne     .L2                         # }while(p != endp)
   ... then a horizontal vector sum ...
        MOVD eax, xmm0
        ret
```

Vectorization is sort of like parallelization and for a reduction like this (summing an array down to scalar) requires associative operations.  e.g. an FP version would only vectorize with `-ffast-math` or with OpenMP.

---

In a general purpose register like RAX that doesn't have instructions to do SIMD addition without carry between byte boundaries (like [`paddb xmm0, xmm1`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/paddb:paddw:paddd:paddq) would), it's called SWAR (SIMD within a register).

This technique was more useful in the past, on ISAs without a proper SIMD instruction set like Alpha or MIPS64.  But it's still possible, and SWAR techniques can be useful as part of something like a popcount without the `popcnt` instruction, e.g. masking out every other bit and shifting so you're effectively doing 32 separate additions (that can't overflow into each other) into 2-bit accumulators.

The popcnt bithack shown in [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer/109025#109025) does that, widening to 4-bit counters then 8-bit, then using a multiply to shift-and-add by 4 different shifts and produce the sum in the high byte.

Answer (score 2):

Registers don't tend to hold instructions, they instead hold data to be worked on by instructions.

However, if you *wanted* to store instructions as data, I believe (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)) that the longest x86 instruction is about fifteen bytes, or 120 bits. So, no, it won't fit into a single 64-bit register.

In terms of holding multiple data values in a single register, that is certainly possible. This is even supported by the hardware, with even the earliest x86 chips having `ah` and `al` which together formed the `ax` register.

Even without that, you can certainly insert/extract "sub-registers" into/from registers, by using the bitwise operations (like `and`, `or`, `not` and `xor`), and the bit shift operations (like `shl`, `shr`, `rol`, and `ror`).

Comment: Sorry, yeah you're right I shall edit the question. But regardless, can they hold multiple different data values at once?

Comment: It's all up to how you look at it. They just store a certain number of bits. What those bits mean to you, if you interpret them as 1 value, 2 values, or maybe even 64 separate values (1-bit flags) is up to you/your program.

Comment: Of course, yes.  A 64-bit register can hold 64 different booleans.  It's all binary data.